# How can I switch from Survival to Creative?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Just like the title states, I'd like to switch from Survival Mode to Creative. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

1. Use a command. In the chat log (press 'T') enter this command

   ```
   /gamemode creative
   ```

   You can also use `/gamemode 1` or `/gamemode c`. These can also be entered into a command block and activated at will.
2. If you don't have cheats enabled, you can "Open to LAN" from the pause menu, allow cheats and use the above method.
3. Re-create your world from the save selection menu. Select a world, then an option to "re-create world" will become available. Here you can choose the game type. (creative, survival, etc). You can also choose "More Options" and select "allow cheats" so you can use the above method as well.

For the record, to switch to survival, `/gamemode s`, `gamemode survival` and `gamemode 0` are the commands to switch to survival.

Comment: i suppose you was typing this when i voted to close as duplicate otherwise you could have saved yourself some time and just suggested to the accepted answer your 2nd point (as that's all the answer was missing, it suggests an alternate way by editing a dat file)

Comment: @Memor-X indeedy, but I suppose (at no intentional offense to the OP) that I doubt they would be willing or brave enough to attempt editing the .dat file... Could be wrong though :)